# Create Site Collection using CSOM for SharePoint 2019 On-Premise

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, csom, sharepoint-on-prem, 2019

We are trying to get Site Collections to be created from CSOM (C#) and are having trouble.  Almost all examples of this found on the Internet are for 2013/2016 SharePoint or SharePoint Online.

In order to "allow" CSOM to create Site Collections, we followed a setup that works in 2013/2016 (link: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vesku/2016/11/24/provisioning-site-collections-with-csom-in-sharepoint-2016/)  Unfortunately, it didn't work for us as it seems that something has changed in SharePoint 2019 and no one has identified it (and shared).

TLDR; We need to create Site Collections in SharePoint 2019 on-premise via CSOM/c# application (aka "not" in SharePoint)

For instance, we run this code in SharePoint 2019 Management Console

```
$siteColUrl = "https://dev.domain.com/sites/admin"
$site = get-spsite -Identity $siteColUrl

$snapin = Get-PSSnapin | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell'}
if ($snapin -eq $null) 
{
    Write-Host "Loading SharePoint Powershell Snapin"
    Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell"
}

$site = get-spsite -Identity $siteColUrl
$site.AdministrationSiteType = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAdministrationSiteType]::TenantAdministration
```

... and it produces these errors:

```
get-spsite : Cannot find an SPSite object with Id or Url: https://dev.domain.com/sites/admin.
At line:2 char:9
+ $site = get-spsite -Identity $siteColUrl
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...SPCmdletGetSite:SPCmdletGetSite) [Get-SPSite], SPCmdletPipeBindException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletGetSite

get-spsite : Cannot find an SPSite object with Id or Url: https://dev.domain.com/sites/admin.
At line:11 char:9
+ $site = get-spsite -Identity $siteColUrl
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...SPCmdletGetSite:SPCmdletGetSite) [Get-SPSite], SPCmdletPipeBindException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletGetSite

The property 'AdministrationSiteType' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At line:12 char:1
+ $site.AdministrationSiteType = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAdministration ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound
```

Also, when we run our C#/CSOM code for the ExecuteQuery command, we get this error:

```
Cannot find stub for type with id \"{268004ae-ef6b-4e9b-8425-127220d84719}\". The specified server may not support APIs used in this operation
```

Supposedly, the fix for this is similar to the setup mentioned in the definetenantadminsite.ps1 PowerShell script from the original blog post.

```
http://sadomovalex.blogspot.com/2015/08/fix-problem-with-missing-api-error-when.html
```

Unfortunately, it has the same error as above (wasn't expected to work since it was the same code essentially).

Answer (score 0):

You need create a site collection "https://dev.domain.com/sites/admin" first.

Then run the PowerShell below.

```
$siteColUrl = "https://dev.domain.com/sites/admin"

$snapin = Get-PSSnapin | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell'}
if ($snapin -eq $null) 
{
    Write-Host "Loading SharePoint Powershell Snapin"
    Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell"
}

$site = get-spsite -Identity $siteColUrl
$site.AdministrationSiteType = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAdministrationSiteType]::TenantAdministration
```

Then prepare the web application(s) to enable the CreateSite CSOM method using PowerShell below.

```
$WebApplicationUrl="https://dev.domain.com"
$snapin = Get-PSSnapin | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell'}
if ($snapin -eq $null) 
{
    Write-Host "Loading SharePoint Powershell Snapin"
    Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell"
}    

$webapp=Get-SPWebApplication $WebApplicationUrl
$newProxyLibrary = New-Object "Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPClientCallableProxyLibrary"
$newProxyLibrary.AssemblyName = "Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.Dedicated.TenantAdmin.ServerStub, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"
$newProxyLibrary.SupportAppAuthentication = $true
$webapp.ClientCallableSettings.ProxyLibraries.Add($newProxyLibrary)
$webapp.SelfServiceSiteCreationEnabled=$true
$webapp.Update()
Write-Host "Successfully added TenantAdmin ServerStub to ClientCallableProxyLibrary for web application" $WebApplicationUrl
# Reset the memory of the web application
Write-Host "IISReset..."    
Restart-Service W3SVC,WAS -force
Write-Host "IISReset complete on this server, remember other servers in farm as well."
```

Refer to: [PowerShell to enable site collection creation with CSOM](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-admin-scripts/tree/master/Scripts/SharePoint.SiteColProvisioning.Configuration)