# Create Modern sites using CSOM for SharePoint 2019 On-Premise

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, modern-team-site

What is the best approach to programatically create a modern (team) site in the SharePoint 2019?

We need to create the sites and do some small customization before running migration.
Since a special logic, I would preffer using C# CSOM/Pnp.Core libs. I am not sure whether this particular step is better to develop in PowerShell (running on the server side) 
Is there any example for this using PowerShell or CSOM ?

I have actually read the [Create Site Collection using CSOM for SharePoint 2019 On-Premise](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/263026/create-site-collection-using-csom-for-sharepoint-2019-on-premise)
,but I am not sure, whether it works also with the modern sites?

Answer (score 1):

After a time I think, the [Create Site Collection using CSOM for SharePoint 2019 On-Premise](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/263026/create-site-collection-using-csom-for-sharepoint-2019-on-premise) can answer my question.

There must be added the TenantAdmin ServerStub to ClientCallableProxyLibrary for web application in order sucesfully create sites via CSOM.

The script for the SP2019/SP2016 allowtenantapiv16.ps1 could be found at https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-admin-scripts/tree/master/Scripts/SharePoint.SiteColProvisioning.Configuration

I still don't know it is the best approach. Using the CSOM and Tenant object, the both tenant.CreateSite(), tenant.CreateSiteCollection() worked. The 2nd one seemed to be faster.

```
            using (var ctxTenant = authMananger.GetNetworkCredentialAuthenticatedContext(tenantUrl, user, pw, domain))
        {
            var tenant = new Tenant(ctxTenant);

            //SiteCreationProperties props = new SiteCreationProperties()
            //{
            //    Title = wi.Title,
            //    //Url = wi.TargetUrl,
            //    Url = "http://myserver/sites/Test1",
            //    Lcid = 1033,
            //    Template = "STS#3",
            //    Owner = domainUser
            //};

            //tenant.CreateSite(props);
            //ctxTenant.ExecuteQuery();

            SiteEntity siteEntity = new SiteEntity()
            {
                Title = wi.Title,
                Url = siteUrl,
                Description = wi.Description,
                Lcid = 1033,
                Template = "STS#3",
                SiteOwnerLogin = domainUser
            };

            tenant.CreateSiteCollection(siteEntity);
```

There is still one small inconvenience - the created site shows on its home page in the right upper corner the "0#.w|< domainUser >" instead of the user name - mightbe because a missing parameter.